# Dell Inspirion 15

Tags: hardware

I just ordered Dell Inspirion 15 (AMD Ryzen™ 5 5500U processor and AMD Radeon GPU). I plan to use the elementary as the only OS, as I used it from 0.4 to 5.1.7 on my old i3 laptop and it worked flawlessly and I love it :)
I wonder if anybody experienced any problem with installing/running the elementary OS on Dell Inspirion 15?

Answer (score 0):

While not on a Dell machine, my Lenovo IdeaPad 5 14ALC05 uses the same CPU as yours. Right off the bat, with eOS5 I had multiple issues, mainly I was unable to change the screen brightness, and in general the system seemed to perform sub-optimally.

Instead of further investigation, I decided to install the second beta of eOS6. Thanks to the newer kernel the system was much more usable, however, Suspend/Sleep, and resume from sleep did not work.

I updated to the latest kernel (version 5.13). The laptop now manages to suspend/sleep correctly, but resuming from sleep still fails. The issue is most probably with the AMD GPU driver, there is a fairly lengthy discussion at [GitLab](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/drm/amd/-/issues/1230). And there is also a post on [AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1345609/wakeup-after-suspend-reboots-ideapad-5-14alc05-under-ubuntu-21-04) that leads to a [reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/linuxhardware/comments/i28nm5/ideapad_14are05_s3_sleep_fix/) with some more advice.

Some report success after manually applying certain patches, others have switched to different distros in the meantime. The bottom line seems to be - the fixes will be part of Kernel 5.14. So, in about 2-3 months it should be possible to have a hassle free experience, with working suspend/sleep.

Please do report back on your experience with running eOS5/6, as I am curious if it's any better on a Dell machine. For now I am on eOS6 beta 2 - sleep does not work, neither does the fingerprint scanner (but I have to confess that I did not investigate the fingerprint scanner at all). The webcam and the microphone work fine, wifi does too.